# FAQ reference on removed question page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, help-center

There is still a reference to the FAQ on the "removed for reasons of moderation" notification page. Should this say Help Center instead (and maybe have a link)?

> [image: Page Not Found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray (a monotone hooray. Think Ben Stein)

It's been fixed.

[image: Fixed]